# Java JFrame button doesn't respond

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am making a simple car rental program in Java for university coursework. Per the requirements for the coursework it requires that I have certain buttons, one for buying a car and one for renting a car. I have a CarToBuy class, a CarToRent class and these are subclasses of the Car class. The JFrame is on it's own class named 'CarCompany'.

The 'Add Car To Buy' button works correctly but the 'Add Car To Rent' button does not even though the code is very similar. CarToBuy calls the methods getDescription, getPrice, getYear and getMileage whereas CarToRent calls getDescription, getadminfee and getdailyrate though I have attempted to get CarToRent to call the same methods yet the button still does not do anything when clicked.

**This is the CarToBuy and CarToRent buttons**

```
public void addCarToBuy()
    {

     CarToBuy newCarToBuy= new CarToBuy (getDescription(), getPrice(), getYear(), getMileage());
                        
        item.add(newCarToBuy);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"A new car to buy has been added");

    }


public void addCarToRent()
    {

     CarToRent newCarToRent= new CarToRent (getDescription(), getadminfee(), getdailyrate());
                        
        item.add(newCarToRent);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"A new car to rent has added");

    }
```

**Here is the JFrame code**

```
frame = new JFrame("CarCompany");
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        
        JLabel priceLable = new JLabel("Price:");
        JLabel yearLable = new JLabel("Year:");
        JLabel mileageLable = new JLabel("Mileage:");
        JLabel emptyspaceLable = new JLabel(" ");
        JLabel emptyspace2Lable = new JLabel(" ");
        
        JLabel sizeLable = new JLabel("Size:");
        
        JLabel descriptionLable = new JLabel("Description:");
        JLabel adminfeeLable = new JLabel("Admin Fee:");
        JLabel dailyrateLable = new JLabel("Daily Rate:");
        
        JLabel customernameLable = new JLabel("Customer Name:");
        JLabel rentaldateLable = new JLabel("Rental Date:");
        JLabel returndateLable = new JLabel("Return Date:");
        JLabel numberofdaysLable = new JLabel("Number of Days:");
        JLabel carnumberLable = new JLabel("Car Number:");
               
        
        
        // TEXTBOXES  
             
        priceTextbox = new JTextField(10);
        yearTextbox = new JTextField(10);
        mileageTextbox = new JTextField(10);
        descriptionTextbox = new JTextField (10);
        adminfeeTextbox = new JTextField (10);
        dailyrateTextbox = new JTextField (10);
        customernameTextbox = new JTextField (10);
        rentaldateTextbox = new JTextField (10);
        returndateTextbox = new JTextField (10);
        numberofdaysTextbox = new JTextField (10);
        carnumberTextbox = new JTextField (10);
               
        
        
        // BUTTONS
                
        addCarToBuyButton = new JButton("Add Car To Buy");
        addCarToBuyButton.addActionListener(this); 
        addCarToRentButton = new JButton("Add Car to Rent");
        addCarToRentButton.addActionListener(this);
        addBuyCarButton = new JButton("Buy Car");
        addBuyCarButton.addActionListener(this);
        addDisplayAllButton = new JButton("Display All");
        addDisplayAllButton.addActionListener(this);
        addRentCarButton = new JButton("Rent Car");
        addRentCarButton.addActionListener(this);
        addClearButton = new JButton("Clear");
        addClearButton.addActionListener(this);
        addReturnCarButton = new JButton("Return Car");
        addReturnCarButton.addActionListener(this);
        
        
        
        // LAYOUT
        
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4));
        
        

        // GUI
        
        contentPane.add(priceLable);
        contentPane.add(yearLable);
        contentPane.add(mileageLable);
        contentPane.add(emptyspaceLable);
        
        contentPane.add(priceTextbox);  
        contentPane.add(yearTextbox);
        contentPane.add(mileageTextbox);
        contentPane.add(addCarToBuyButton);
        
        contentPane.add(descriptionLable);
        contentPane.add(adminfeeLable);
        contentPane.add(dailyrateLable);
        contentPane.add(emptyspace2Lable);
                
        contentPane.add(descriptionTextbox);
        contentPane.add(adminfeeTextbox);
        contentPane.add(dailyrateTextbox);
        contentPane.add(addCarToRentButton);
        
        contentPane.add(customernameLable);
        contentPane.add(rentaldateLable);
        contentPane.add(returndateLable);
        contentPane.add(numberofdaysLable);
        
        contentPane.add(customernameTextbox);
        contentPane.add(rentaldateTextbox);
        contentPane.add(returndateTextbox);
        contentPane.add(numberofdaysTextbox);
        
        contentPane.add(carnumberLable);
        contentPane.add(addBuyCarButton);
        contentPane.add(addRentCarButton);
        contentPane.add(addReturnCarButton);
        
        contentPane.add(carnumberTextbox);
        contentPane.add(addDisplayAllButton);
        contentPane.add(addClearButton);
                
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

**The action code for the buttons is here**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

        String command = event.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("Add Car To Buy")) {
            addCarToBuy();
        }

        if (command.equals("Add Car To Rent")) {
            addCarToRent();
        }

    }
```

**These are the methods that are being called**

```
public String getDescription()

    {

        String aDescription=descriptionTextbox.getText();
        return aDescription;

    }
    
    public int getPrice()
    {
        
        int aPrice=Integer.parseInt(priceTextbox.getText());
        return aPrice;

    }
    
    public int getYear()
    {
        
        int aYear=Integer.parseInt(yearTextbox.getText());
        return aYear;

    }
    
    public int getMileage()
    {
        
        Integer aMileage=Integer.parseInt(mileageTextbox.getText());
        return aMileage;

    }
    
    public int getadminfee()

    {

        int aadminfee=Integer.parseInt(adminfeeTextbox.getText());
        return aadminfee;

    }
    
    public int getdailyrate()

    {

        int adailyrate=Integer.parseInt(dailyrateTextbox.getText());
        return adailyrate;
        
    }
```

**I'll also put here the constructor for the CarToBuy and CarToRent classes**

```
public CarToRent(String thecarDescription, int carAdminFee, int carDailyRate)
    {
        super(thecarDescription);
        adminFee = carAdminFee;
        dailyRate = carDailyRate;
        rentDate = "";
        returnDate = "";
        daysRented = 0;
        totalAccumulated = 0;
        onLoan = false;
    }

public CarToBuy(String thecarDescription, int carPrice, int regYear, int carMileage)
    {
        super(thecarDescription);
        price = carPrice;
        year = regYear;
        mileage = carMileage;
        sold = false;
    }
```

Any help on figuring out why the 'Add Car To Rent' button doesn't do anything would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You didn't show any UI code but only your model. With only that information we can't tell anything. Did you register an action or action listener on all your buttons? Did you verify (ideally using a debugger) that those are being called?

Comment: `new JButton("Add Car to Rent")` uses a lowercase `t`, while `if (command.equals("Add Car To Rent"))` uses an uppercase `T`.  You could have spotted this by adding `System.out.println(command);` to your actionPerformed method.  You may want to use `if (action.getSource() == addCarToRentButton)` instead, so your code won’t be vulnerable to a typo.